# Updating from ASP.NET Core 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I am in the process of updating an ASP.NET Core project from 1.0 to 2.0, I have everything but the EF CLI working.

The problem is using environment variables for database connection settings, in 1.0 I was using the solution explained here: 
https://www.benday.com/2017/02/17/ef-core-migrations-without-hard-coding-a-connection-string-using-idbcontextfactory/

After updating to 2.0 I am getting the following error: [image]

I have been looking for other patterns, that would allow for environment variables in EF commands, but without luck.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://wildermuth.com/2017/07/06/Program-cs-in-ASP-NET-Core-2-0)

Comment: Not sure how I missed that article, good stuff. I would, however, like to get it working with IDesignTimeDbContextFactory. Seems much cleaner.

Comment: Yeah, but in this case you'll have to hard code connection string, don't you ?

Comment: That is a good question, in 1.0 it was possible to create a new ConfigurationBuilder and then include environment variables. But that solution does not work in 1.1 and 2.0.

Comment: Yeah, alternative is dump `BuildWebHost` method in `Program.cs` but it looks weird, because you have to check  `_config["DesignTime"] != "true"` in `Startup`